# Save checkedlistbox checked items to access2013 database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have checkedlistbox that contains five items A, B, C, D, E, in my project. 
here is my programming code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\testing.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*****")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", con)
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (combo, L1, L2, L3, L4) VALUES (@combo, @L1, @L2, @L3, @L4)"
        For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString)
            ElseIf i = 1 Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L1", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString)
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L2", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString)
            ElseIf i = 3 Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L3", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString)
            ElseIf i = 4 Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L4", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString)
            End If
        Next
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
'code end
```

so my question is when i have checked all items in checkedlistbox this code works for me fine but when i select less than five items it gives me error that "**No value given for one or more required parameters**".

Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try change loop code:

```
'set default value
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo", "false")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L1", "false")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L2", "false")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L3", "false")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L4", "false")

For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        Select Case CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices(i)
            Case 0
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i).ToString)
            Case 1
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L1", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i).ToString)
            Case 2
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L2", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i).ToString)
            Case 3
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L3", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i).ToString)
            Case 4
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L4", CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i).ToString)
        End Select
Next
```

Comment: @ c4pricorn Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion loop code but same error occurs.  "No value given for one or more required parameters".

Comment: It seems that the parameter must have any value other than "" if item is not checked. Try modify code to add value "false" or something, if item not checked. Or add all parameters with value="false" before loop.